# What are the explanations for below WSO2 DSS error codes

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, error-code

I would like to know explanations for below error codes which is thrown from WSO2 DSS.

```
DATABASE_ERROR
CONNECTION_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR
VALIDATION_ERROR
INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR
UNKNOWN_ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATABASE_ERROR - Database errors occurring such as SQLExceptions when creating a query in the data service level
CONNECTION_UNAVAILABLE_ERROR - Erors occurring while initializing connections in JNDI datasources 
VALIDATION_ERROR - Errors occurring when using validators, essentially when a validation fails 
INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR - Errors occurring while converting a query's ExternalParams to parameters by making necessary transformation as instructed by with-param elements
UNKNOWN_ERROR - Any error does not fall into the above categories
```